# hidden variable in R

Tags: api, r

I am using the RLastFM package, and have some question about the function:

```
> tag.getTopArtists
function (tag, key = lastkey, parse = TRUE) 
{
    params = list(method = "tag.gettopartists", tag = tag, api_key = lastkey)
    ret = getForm(baseurl, .params = params)
    doc = xmlParse(ret, asText = TRUE)
    if (parse) 
        doc = p.tag.gettopartists(doc)
    return(doc)
}
```

the author included lastkey as the api_key, but I can't find it by using ls(), where is it?

Thanks.

Comment: First - as the author of that package I'm glad that someone beside me is using it. I'd appreciate any feedback you may have. As to the key location, do you have your own API key that you would like to replace the lastkey with? I believe that `GlobalEnv` is higher in the search path than a loaded package, so if you have your own global variable called `lastkey`, it should replace the default key in function calls.

Comment: @Greg When I do `lastkey<-"X";debug(tag.getTopArtists);tag.getTopArtists()` then inside function original `key` is visible. And BTW why you define `key`argument when you don't use it inside a function (`api_key=lastkey` shouldn't be `api_key=key`?).

Comment: @Marek - that is a vestige of an older key handling system I had in earlier versions of the package. It's been a while since I looked at it but I will take a look and clean that up. The parameter list uses lastkey. I need to fix a few build issues anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getAnywhere(lastkey)` show you where it is and `RLastFM:::lastkey` gives you this value. The value isn't exported from namespace of package.

For more details check [Writing R Extensions manual, Package name spaces section](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-name-spaces).